# PHP Get the word replaced by preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

How can I get the replaced word by preg_replace() function.

```
preg_replace('/[@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/', '<a href="/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>', $post );
```

I want to get `$1` variable so that I can user it further.

Comment: Dont understand your question. Can you make an example please?

Comment: When someone mentions(uses something like @hammad) a user in his post, I covert the mention into a link by using the code in the question. But the problem is that I want to get the mentioned user noticed that he was mentioned so I want that  **username** which is  being replaced. Hope you understood!

Comment: use this `[@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)` regex in preg_match_all. And get the desired string from index 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace and retrieve placeholder value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429729/replace-and-retrieve-placeholder-value)

Answer (score 1):

Capture it before you replace the expression:

```
// This is where the match will be kept
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/[@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/';

// Check if there are matches and capture the user (first group)
if (preg_match($pattern, $post, $matches)) {
    // First match is the user
    $user = $matches[1];

    // Do the replace
    preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>', $post );
}
```

Comment: Will the match contain the @ symbol?

Comment: No, it will not, it will contain the charactes inside the first parenthesis - ([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with `preg_replace()` as it returns the finished string/array, but does not preserve the replaced phrases. You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to manually achieve this.

```
$pattern = '/[@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/';
$subject = '@jurgemaister foo @hynner';
$tokens = array();

$result = preg_replace_callback(
              $pattern,
              function($matches) use(&$tokens) {
                  $tokens[] = $matches[1];
                  return '<a href="/'.$matches[1].'" target="_blank">'.$matches[0].'</a>';
              },
              $subject
          );

echo $result;
// <a href="/jurgemaister" target="_blank">@jurgemaister</a> foo <a href="/hynner" target="_blank">@hynner</a>
print_r($tokens);
// Array
// (
//    [0] => jurgemaister
//    [1] => hynner
// )
```

Comment: -1 for global (can be replaced with use(&$token) also this solution will only work if only one mention is present in the $subject

Comment: I replaced global with use.

Comment: well there is still the problem that it wont work properly with multiple mentions

Comment: @hynner I misunderstood you. I thought you meant multiple mentions of the same name. See my updated solution.

Comment: it's better now but I still like my own answer more than yours :-)

Comment: @hynner The difference is that in my solution you've saved the backreferences in an array to use later which is the most correct answer to OP's question "I want to get $1 variable so that I can user it further."

Comment: in a comment below his question he says that he wants to notify the user. I didn't say your answer was worse, I just like mine more :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use preg_match in addition to preg_replace.  preg_replace is just for replacing.

```
$regex = '/[@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/';
preg_match($regex, $post, $matches);
preg_replace($regex, '<a href="/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>', $post );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with preg_replace, but you can do it with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches){
notify_user($matches[1]); 
return "<a href='/$matches[1]' target='_blank'>$matches[0]</a>";
}, $post);
```

replace `notify_user` with whatever you would call to notify the user.
This can also be modified to check whether the user exists and replace only valid mentions.